# Find matching patterns in list of log files where patterns are stored in array elements

Tags: arrays, bash, shell, awk, scripting

I have a list of log files which have the same pattern example :

"http://textuploader.com/d02at!"

As you can see it's divided into various columns , I want to extract certain information from each column i.e EBCDIC, BINARY and TRACE HEADERS and display it column wise for each sequence.

I have already written a working script to do so :

http://textuploader.com/d0z0u

Which generates the desired output in the following format :

EBCDIC Header info 
"http://textuploader.com/d02aq!"

Bnary Header Info
"http://textuploader.com/d02am!"

Trace Header parts 
"http://textuploader.com/d02ap!"

..Similar extraction for other headers based on the first column in the logfile.

What I want to do is to getaway from so much "grep" work in the script and use some sort of array method to store all the attributes that I want to grep.

Then iterate over these array elements to extract the information.

Thanks

Comment: @Ed Morton I have edited the question , but since the script is not working  I don't have an immediate output.

Comment: What I am trying to achieve is to create a report by extracting values stored at same place from different log files and display them in the form of a table :

Comment: `logfile_1  value1  value2  value3 ........Value(n)`

Comment: same for logfile_2 to logfile(n)

Comment: Got it, I will edit it appropriately. Thanks..

Comment: @Ed Morton .. I have updated my question.

Comment: Asking a question is very simple - show concise, testable sample input plus expected output plus what you've tried so far and state your requirements. Certainly do not expected people to go clicking around the internet trying to piece together your question, nor should you expect them to read more than 10 lines or so per input file. It's up to you to make your samples **concise** as we're all happy to help but busy so we need **you** to put the effort into making the question concise. Best I can suggest is to once again read [ask] and then try again to post an acceptable question. Good luck!

Comment: Well, you could create a Bash array with all the grep patterns, another array with all the corresponding AWK code snippets, and another one with all the corresponding output files, then iterate with a `for` loop over all the indices with a command like this in the `for` loop: `grep "${grep[$i]}" | awk "${awk[$i]}" >>"${out[$i]}"`.